# CSS - Submenu disappears when I try to hover

Tags: css

I looked through similar threads and tried a few solutions (`z-index`, `position`, trying to identify overlapping elements) and can't figure out why whenever I try to click on a submenu item, it disappears. Page is below:

http://aboutbeingconnected.com/consulting/

The only menu tab with the submenu is 'Consulting'.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not links

Comment: Sorry about that. Wasn't even sure where the issue was. Will do that next time.

Comment: Do it _this_ time. You can edit your question. If Guy's answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Due to your submenu being `position: absolute` with a `top: 40px` this means there is `40px` gap below the `li`. When your mouse moves off the `li` and into the `40px` you are  no longer hovering over the `li`, and thus `li:hover` is not triggered.

One solution is to set the `top` to be 100% of the parent element:

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul {
  top: 100%;
}
```

This will reduce the gap between parent and child menus, but you can see how there is now no gap between elements.

Comment: Awesome! That worked great.

--**bows**--

Comment: No worries, you can mark the answer as correct so others may find the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

It all comes down to the 40px gap set with .sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {top: 40px}.

Absolute positioning pulls the submenu out of the flow of the document - even though it's still in the HTML as a descendant of the parent li, it no longer resides within its boundaries. So try to mouse from one to the other and you've left the li, canceling its hover behavior, before you get close to the submenu.

How to retain the same look and get the expected functionality you wish you had:

1. No more position absolute for .sf-menu ul. Keep it in the document flow.
2. Apply a background image of the little up-arrow to the UL. Add extra white-stripe at the top if you want more visual space.
3. Apply a background image / color of the gray to the li. Apply top and bottom padding to get the look you need. (Margin will do too if you don't need it to be clickable area.)